# Accessing values inside Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to print a 2d array of a schedule that is inputted to me via object. When it prints, it is not giving me the values I want. Any idea what i doing wrong when digging into the object values?

Heres the schedule given to me:

```
var schedule = {
"Mon": [undefined, "Bowser", undefined, undefined, undefined, "Ladykiller"],
"Tues": [undefined, undefined, "Fifi", undefined, undefined, undefined],
"Wed": [undefined, undefined, undefined, "Spike", undefined, undefined],
"Thurs":[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
}
```

Heres my code trying to add it to an array and print it:

```
function printSchedule(schedule){

var mySchedule = [["    ", "Mon   ", "Tue   ", "Wed   ", "Thu   "],
                ["9am", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      "],
                ["10am", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      "],
                ["11am", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      "],
                ["12am", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      "],
                ["1pm", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      "],
                ["2pm", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      "]];


for(var property in schedule){

  if(property === "Mon"){
    for(var i = 0; i < property.length; i++){
      if(property[i] !== undefined){
        mySchedule[1][i + 1] = property[i];
      }
    }
  }

  else if(property === "Tue"){
    for(var i = 0; i < property.length; i++){
      if(property[i] !== undefined){
        mySchedule[2][i + 1] = property[i];
      }
    }
  }

  else if(property === "Wed"){
    for(var i = 0; i < property.length; i++){
      if(property[i] !== undefined){
        mySchedule[3][i + 1] = property[i];
      }
    }
  }

  else if(property === "Thu"){
    for(var i = 0; i < property.length; i++){
      if(property[i] !== undefined){
        mySchedule[4][i + 1] = property[i];
      }
    }
  }
}
console.table(mySchedule)
}
```

Current output is giving me things like "M" "o" "T" when I really just want the string that was inside the object. Thanks!

Comment: `property` is a string like `"Mon"`, so `property[i]` is a character from the string. E.g. `property[1]` is `"o"`.

Comment: Why are you looping over `property` in your `for` loops? Shouldn't yuou be looping over `schedule[property]`?

Comment: @Barmar thank you so much! with your pointers i was able to get it running perfectly. u rock man

Answer (score 0):

[edit] Wow, someone actually edited a five year old question...

There is a lot of redundant (copy pasted) code. So I wrote a shorter script, and flipped the table to make it it easier to parse the schedule object.

`printTimetable()` is mostly to showcase the output. I'm assuming that you want to print this to an HTML table so the formatting doesn't really matter for now.

```js
var schedule = {
  "Mon":   [undefined, "Bowser", undefined, undefined, undefined, "Ladykiller"],
  "Tues":  [undefined, undefined, "Fifi", undefined, undefined, undefined],
  "Wed":   [undefined, undefined, undefined, "Spike", undefined, undefined],
  "Thurs": [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
};

function createTimetable(schedule) {
  let table = [], day = '', shortenedDay = '';
  
  let firstRow = [,'9am', '10am', '11am', '12am', '1pm', '2pm'];
  
  table.push(firstRow);
  
  for (let day in schedule) {
    shortenedDay = day.slice(0,3);
    hours = [shortenedDay, ...schedule[day]];
    table.push(hours);
  }

  return table;
}

function printTimetable(timetable) {
  for (let row of timetable) {
    console.log(row.toString());
  }
  
  console.table(timetable)
}

printTimetable( createTimetable(schedule) );
```

If you want me to fix and reducing your original code, I would go with something like this:

```js
var schedule = {
  "Mon":   [undefined, "Bowser", undefined, undefined, undefined, "Ladykiller"],
  "Tues":  [undefined, undefined, "Fifi", undefined, undefined, undefined],
  "Wed":   [undefined, undefined, undefined, "Spike", undefined, undefined],
  "Thurs": [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
}


function printSchedule(schedule) {

  var mySchedule = [
    ["    ", "Mon   ", "Tue   ", "Wed   ", "Thu   "],
    ["9am", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      "],
    ["10am", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      "],
    ["11am", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      "],
    ["12am", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      "],
    ["1pm", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      "],
    ["2pm", "      ", "      ", "      ", "      "]
  ];

  let days = mySchedule[0].map(day => day.trim());

  for (let day in schedule) {
    let shorterDay = day.slice(0, 3);
    let index = days.indexOf(shorterDay);

    for (var i = 0; i < schedule[day].length; i++) {
      if (schedule[day][i] !== undefined) {
        mySchedule[i + 1][index] = schedule[day][i];
      }
    }
  }

  console.log('open the console (F12)');
  console.table(mySchedule)
}

printSchedule(schedule)
```